# Upgrade to 5.x failed

Tags: updates, upgrades, craft5

I followed the [upgrade instructions](https://craftcms.com/docs/5.x/upgrade.html). My current version is 4.8.1. When I run `composer update`, I get the following error:
[image]

I added the following code to composer.json because of another issue:

```
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
```

How can I solve the error message to upgrade to 5.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to change your dependency on `craftcms/generator` in your `composer.json` file to this (it's likely in the `require-dev` section):

```json
"craftcms/generator": "^2.0.0"
```

Alternatively, if you don't actually use [Craft Generator](https://github.com/craftcms/generator), you can remove the dependency altogether.

Comment: Thank you. That worked exactly as it should and I was able to complete the upgrade to version 5.x-beta.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it looks like ... you have to uninstall the generator plugin at first?

Comment: I didn't want to delete it because it was delivered out-of-the box with Craft CMS. Requiring another version for the generator solved my issue.